# Need to place constant images beside GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview, android-linearlayout

How can I arrange constant images parallely  . I'm using gridview to display the images. But,not able to achieve this: Putting constant images beside Gridview (on both the sides i.e, Left & Right side)
Please help me how to use the layouts properly..

Currently my grid layout is occupying the space for constant images.... Please help me on this..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make two separate fragments in your application. In one put the Grid View which I believe, you might want to change dynamically. In the other fragment, keep your images that are supposed to be constant and keep this fragment as it is, as you would like to keep the images constant.

For a simple tutorial on Fragments, follow this : http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/05/android-fragments-api/

Comment: Now its working for me... 
<LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout>
.......Left side Constant Images...........
 </LinearLayout>

 <FrameLayout>
  <GridView/> -->Parent
  GridView1/> -->Child
</FrameLayout>

 <LinearLayout>
.......Constant Images Right...........
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

But, the problem is SCALING.. 

I have to maintain 3 rows in each gridview.
The problem is SCALING.. 

The SIZE of constant images & Gridview Images should be same.. Both should be on same level..

I'm not able to achieve this perfect style.. How can I approach to get it.

Please ehelp me on this.. Thanks

Comment: @laki : are you not able to set the size of the ImageView in the xml files ? If not, then try doing it programatically like this.

Comment: Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();            imageView.setLayoutParams(new View.LayoutParams(width/3,height));